# Валидация формы на сервере

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

В этом примере показано как нужно делать валидацию введенных данных на форме:
[Проверка введенных данных](https://spring-projects.ru/guides/validating-form-input/)

А разве это правильно делать валидацию на сервере?
Я думал, что валидацию должен делать frontend.

Comment: Валидацию фронтенда можно обойти напрямую отправив запрос на сервер. Поэтому ВАЖНО не доверять фронтенду и выполнять валидацию и на стороне сервера.

Comment: Хорошей практикой, является создание прослойки между контроллерами и сервисами приложения, в которой проверяются данные прилетевшие на контроллер.

Comment: А стоит ли доверять ее thymeleaf+Spring? Может на сервере лучше ее делать вручную?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы делаете своё приложение в соответствии с паттерном MVC *(что правильно)*, то у вас будет отдельный слой для работы с фронтендом, обычно он называется `web`, в нём размещаются контроллеры/сервлеты.

Ваш JavaScript кто угодно может поменять или отправить запрос напрямую. Разумеется, логика проверки и валидации должна быть инкапсулирована и сокрыта от посторонних глаз.